# Problema al subir archivos a firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Tengo este problema al tratar de crear la referencia para actualizar datos en el **firestore** me lanza este error

> Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): Function
>   CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type
>   non-empty string, but it was: undefined

```
this.db.collection("usersInCreation").doc(user.uid).update({
   photoURL : imageRef
})
```

esto es lo único que tengo nada mas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que esta dando es por que user.uid esta llegando un valor undefined

Comment: efectivamente este era el problema muchas gracias amigo encontré como solucionar ese problema